# How do I determine what's causing my Terminology terminal startup lag?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, fish, terminology

I've noticed recently that my Terminology terminal emulator lags when I open it up. It takes about 10 seconds to open a new window after I launch. Once it's open however, I don't notice any lag.

I am running Terminology 1.7.99 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS with fish shell. I haven't installed updates recently as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Check any RC files that are loaded. In bash this is .bashrc or similar, so I guess look for .fishrc or similar. Any of those that contain expensive commands is likely the culprit.

Comment: I have a minimal config.fish (just a single line) and only a few functions. I can launch my default Gnome terminal more or less instantly. It's only the Terminology that lags.